# How to get the domain of a specific cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

There is a web site `www.example.com`
All cookies are set to the `www` subdomain.
Now there is a new subdomain and I want the cookies to be seen for all subdomains.

The goal is to rewrite the `www.example.com` cookies for all the old visitors to be `.example.com`  or to write new ones for `.example.com` if set for `www.`

For this I want to get the domain of the existing cookies.
Is it possible? Is there a php function for this purpose?

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setDomain($domain)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie). While you can't access the `domain` property of cookies that have already been sent (and set on the client), you can simply set new ones. That will work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the domain is available when reading cookies, this is limited by the browser. A solution would be to remove the old cookie and change it to the new domain.

E.g.

```
$value = $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
setcookie("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "www.example.com");
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), ".example.com");
```

Comment: I had this idea, but this way even after all the cookies changed, the process will be repeated forever. I am doing it on server-side. And another thing: Google Chrome does knows the cookie domain (in Inspect Element)

Comment: You could add another cookie to let you know you've already made the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to change the domain of the cookies currently existing on the clients?

This is not possible(*).

When getting a cookie server side, is it possible for you to see if it was set for the www domain, keeping in mind that the cookie passed form the client has no domain information?

(*) It might be possible with JavaScript on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP function session_get_cookie_params(). I hope this will make the job.

```
domain:"www.domain_name.com"
httponly:false
lifetime:1525181833
path:"/"
secure:false
```

Comment: be carefull : https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-get-cookie-params.php#119445 . I made cookie with httpOnly true, and this function showed it is false

Comment: session_get_cookie_param() only gets the settings defined in php.ini for the session cookie (used with session_start(), $_SESSION, etc.), not the informations about the actual cookie