# Migrate cookie domain from no domain to .mydomain.com with PHP/Nginx

Tags: php, cookies, nginx, cross-domain

I have a web site wrote with PHP and running on Nginx HTTP server. I have a cookie called "locale" which represents the user locale. For 6 months, I am sending the cookie like this:

```
setCookie("locale", "fr", time() + 36000, "/");
```

As a cookie less domain, I understand it's only available on my single domain "www.mydomain.com".

But now, I want to create 2 news sub domains:

1. m.mydomain.com (the mobile part)
2. secure.mydomain.com (a secure version)

I see "locale" cookie set on www is not accessible by m or secure. So now I am sending the cookie like this:

```
setCookie("locale", "fr", time() + 36000, "/", ".mydomain.com");
```

Yeah my cookie is available everywhere now! But as I have some users who had already browsed my web site, they have the domain less cookie + the new one, their browser send me both cookies but PHP gives me the former one. As a result nobody can change the locale any more.

Question is: how can I migrate from this domain less cookie to a domain specified cookie? Without change the cookie name.

Answer (score 0):

The first cookie you set without the domain defaulted to www.mydomain.com and because that's more specific than '.mydomain.com' it's choosing the original cookie. Read the accepted answer here.

[How to get the domain of a specific cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913452/how-to-get-the-domain-of-a-specific-cookie)

Comment: Do you think it's possible to delete the domain less cookie only if it's here?

Comment: what you can do it overwrite the www.mydomain.com cookie and set it to some time in the past so it expires

Comment: BTW, domain less cookie !=== cookie on www.mydomain.com. So to delete a domain less cookie, you must let the domain parameter empty.

Answer (score 0):

As conclusion, I will put this in my index.php file during 1 week:

```
setCookie('locale', null, time() - 5000, '/');
```

In order to delete the domain-less cookie. I have tested on all major browser, and I don't see any conflict with:

```
setCookie('locale', 'fr', time() + 36000, '/', '.mydomain.com');
```